# Oracle DB - special characters in contains function

Tags: java, sql, oracle, special-characters, contains

i have a BLOB field which stores some document contents.

And my Java program want to do a searching on that field ,

here is my SQL statement :

```
Select * from table_A where CONTAINS(BLOB_FIELD,'{Keyword}') > 0;
```

When user input 'P-' and 'P=' , they got the some result.
I want to resolve the problem , thank you!!!

Comment: I found that 'P-' , 'P=' ,'P"' all output the same result when the BLOB_FIELD contains 'P.1/1'( page number)

Comment: What type of document is storing in BLOB_FIELD ? (pdf, doc?)

Answer (score 0):

CONTAINS uses a number of characters/words that have to be escaped if you want to search for the actual character (-,=,*,%,etc). Try 'P\-' and see if that helps... if not see below.

Also the odds are pretty high that your LEXER setting is determining that a period after the P determines a word break (end of sentence). This is controlled by the DBA and has some fairly complex logic to determine how words are split/not split for text searching.

Comment: Thank you but add '' is fail .

Comment: As I stated the ones I listed are just a few of the many characters that contains considers "special". * is another one of those.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqspcl.htm#CCREF2093   edit: I just noticed that the backslash character needs to be escaped when posting here.

Comment: I have already read that docs from Oracle but did not help and i have escaped the character with {} but the problem still exist.

Comment: Did you check the lexer settings for word breaks like I suggested?

Comment: That is advanced for me but i trying to find how to adjust that setting.

And also i cannot find words with Oracle Reserved Words by using CONTAINS(BLOB_FIELD,'{Keyword}') > 0 , is that a way to solve or no solution??(Some reserved words are common , like 'OF' 'AND'.......)

Thanks alot for helping me.

Comment: Found that 'the' cannot be searched and others like 'of' can be search